# Rails activerecord saved data are all nil/null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am a beginner in all this and I am trying to build a very basic controller.

This is my write/create method:

It checks if an id is included in the params. If there is an ID, it does a put request to update an existing car. Otherwise, it just creates a new Car.

```
def write
    if params[ :id ]
      @car = Car.where( id: params[ :id ] ).first
      params[ :car ].each do | key, value |
        attribute = { "#{ key }": value }
        @car.update_attributes( attribute )
      end
    else
      @car = Car.new( 
                model: params[ :model ], 
                num_wheels: params[ :num_wheels ], 
                color: params[ :color ], 
                realm_uuid: params[ :realm_uuid ] 
              )      
    end

    @car.save!
    render json: @car
  end
```

This is my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  scope '/api' do
    get '/' => 'cars#query'
    post '/' => 'cars#write'

    scope '/:id' do
      get '/' => 'cars#read'
      put '/' => 'cars#write'
      delete '/' => 'cars#delete'
    end
  end

end
```

And finally my car.rb:

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord

    attr_accessor :model, :num_wheels, :color, :realm_uuid

end
```

All the routes work correctly, I can create, read, update, and delete. The thing is that when I read, all the values are nil/null. When I make a post in Postman, the `render json: @car` returns a correct car with all the values but when I make a get request, it says all the values are nil/null.

I also see an error: `ArgumentError (Wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 4)` This probably has something to do with it...

Comment: ```If there is an ID, it does a put request to update an existing car. Otherwise, it just creates a new Car.``` - this is how RESTful API works in Rails. See Resource Routing: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default . So why to reinvent the wheel and fight the framework, when you can achieve the same goal with standard tools, such as Rail resources?

Comment: As an aside, `update_attributes` is an alias for `update` and that ["Updates the attributes of the model from the passed-in hash and saves the record..."](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update) so updating the attributes one-by-one like that is a lot more work and database traffic than you need and you're ignoring the return value. Also, `where(id: x).first` really should be `find(x)` or, if you're prepared to get a `nil` back (which you're not), `find_by(id: x)`. Also and what @IlyaKonyukhov said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`attr_accessor` on a model makes an reader/writer method for instance variable with corresponding name.

In your case it overrides getter/setters for model attributes and thus you write to variable instead of attribute. So remove `attr_accessor` and model should save correctly.

If you do not have these fields in db - then you should make a migration to add them.

Comment: my model does have all those fields.

Comment: then remove `attr_accessor` to make rails' ones work

Comment: Oh wow, that worked. Thank you Vasfed! I know attr_accessor allows for reading/writing/etc but I didn't know that would mess with my controller functions.